# Disable RootLogin ssh

Tags: server, ssh

I’m relatively new to Ubuntu. I have successfully setup SSH on my Ubuntu desktop (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS). I am trying to **stop root login**, but cannot find the line **‘PermitRootLogin’**  anywhere in the sshd_config file (/etc/ssh/sshd_config). I even tried adding  ‘**PermitRootLogin no**’ manually to sshd_config file, but it still lets me log in as root. I even restarted the desktop/ including the ssh service .

I would appreciate some expert advice on this issue.

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120

PermitRootLogin prohibit-password

StrictModes yes
```

Comment: to *"stop root login"* or to *"stop root login on SSH"*? How do you try?

Comment: You are missing `PasswordAuthentication yes` ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the sshd config file with vi, press / and type 'Root' and hit enter. That will search for the next occurrence of the word, 'Root'. Press n to repeat the search and find the next occurrence. Repeatedly hit n to find the statement you are looking for. It should be 'PermitRootLogin' followed by 'no'. There is also a setting to allow root login only with ssh keys, 'without-password'.

Comment: PermitRootLogin does not exist anywhere on the sshd_config.

Comment: can you please post your sshd config file, please?

Comment: I think there is character limits. So I will copy & past each section at a time

Comment: # Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2

Comment: is there a way to add txt based attachment?

Comment: Try adding another answer to your question, it may allow more characters.

Comment: please sse the link http://txt.do/d565a or http://textuploader.com/d565a!

Comment: sorry it should say, please see the link to see the textfile sshd_config. I uploaded to http://txt.do/d565a or http://textuploader.com/d565a!

Comment: 'PermitRootLogin prohibit-password' - This line means that Root is only able to log in with pregenerated ssh keys. If you are still able to ssh in as root using a password, there is something else wrong. Make sure that you save the file successfully, and restart the service after editing the file with 'sudo systemctl restart sshd'.
**PermitRootLogin prohibit-password**

Comment: i'm able to login without using ssh key with the password.

Comment: Also tried #PermitRootLogin prohibit-password (disable) and adding PermitRootLogin no -- And restarted the desktop and it still let me login as root.  Not sure whats wrong anymore.

Comment: Did you add PermitRootLogin no, leaving the original PermitRootLogin without-password statement, or did you replace the without-password with no?
  What is the ip/dns hostname of your server, are you logging in to the right one, and is dns resolving correctly?
  Can you run 'sudo netstat -nalp | grep 22' and post the output?

Comment: I tried the both methods and i can still login as root.

Comment: Is dns resolving correctly and you are logging into the correct server? Can you run 'sudo netstat -nalp | grep 22' and post the output to tell what daemon is listening on port 22?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct machine and i'm using IP address.

Comment: I resloved the problme by using DenyUsers root admin12

Comment: I did not think of using the DenyUsers directive. Good job, please post again if you have any more issues!